# PySpark Dataframe Map Function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark and attempting to read in a json file using sqlContext and apply the map() or mapPartition() functions to a function to process the contents of the file concurrently.

```
def func(param_i, param2)

df = sqlContext.read.json(file)
full_arr = df.toJSON().collect()
```

When I iteratively apply the function (below)

```
    i = 0
    while i < total_count:
        arr = full_arr[i:i+chunk_size]
        function(arr, 'foo')
        i = i + chunk_size
```

The function executes properly. However, when I try to apply the map function to the rdd of the DataFrame, each concurrent function call passes in '|' to the function rather than the line of JSON.

```
print(df.rdd.map(lambda i: func(i, 'foo')).collect())
```

```
print(df.rdd.map(lambda i: func(i.toJson(), 'foo')).collect())
```

Comment: Show us some data and the intended output. It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. What version of pyspark are you using? I ask because simply calling `sqlContext.read.json(file)` without providing a schema is disallowed since spark 2.3